# How to insert foreach after echo?

Tags: php, wordpress

this might be a stupid question so please accept my apologies.

I have written a code snippet for a wordpress website that lists restaurants. You enter the instagram id of the venues (if they have one) and it shows the latest instagram photos they've uploaded. If the instagram id value is left empty, i want it to echo nothing. I've written the code and it works fine for places with instagram id's, but as I'm unable the last piece of code (that starts with foreach) inside the echo section, it tries to show it even when the id is empty hence i get a "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in" error. Can you help me out so that I can include that code inside the echo part, so that it won't call that code when id is empty? Thanks very much in advance.

```
  <?php
if ( $instagramid ) {
 echo "


<br><br>
<span style=\"float:left; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 14px;
float: left;
line-height: 32px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top:12px;
padding: 0px 3px 0px 5px;
\">
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\"><img width=\"80\" border=\"1px\" src=\"".$profilepic."\"></a></span>
<br>
<div style=\"margin-left: 50px;\">
     <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 75.00%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4\">
       <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \"><a style=\"color: #3f729b; font-weight: bold; \" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\">".$username."</a> @ instagram</span>
    </div>
    <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 82.00%;\">
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Photos<br>
<span style=\"
font-weight: bold; \"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$sayi."</span></span></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 1.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Followers<br>
 <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipci."</span></span></b></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 0.50%;
   width: 31.00%;\">
          <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Following<br><span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipediyor."</span></span></span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <br><br>


        ";
}
else {
echo "";
}
?>



<?php foreach ($result->data as $fotos): ?>


        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <span style="font-size: 12px; float:left; 
margin:5px 0 2px 10px;">  
<a target="_blank" class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $fotos->link ?>">
<img width="90" src="<?= $fotos->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<span style="font-weight:bold; float:left;"></span>
<span style="float:right;"><span style="color:red; font-weight: bolder;">❤ </span><?= $fotos->likes->count ?></span>
    </span><?php endforeach //Biter ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the loop in your if-block?

Comment: Any reason why you print all that HTML as a string? You can just close the PHP tag (`?>`) and reopen it when the PHP continues.

Comment: Would be nicer have css classes dealing all those styles instead of a bunch of information in style attribute, just a thought.

Comment: How can I use the loop block? I'm quite new in php, so it's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: put the foreach loop in the { } of the else statement.

Comment: Can you show where `$result->data` is being generated? I can't find in your code. But i guess @flowit is right. You probably just need to put that foreach inside the if statement, after the `echo`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like someone said you need to put your loop in if statment like this

```
<?php
if ( $instagramid ) {

// Your old code is here "your echo"
// but before end of if statment, and after echo"" put loop

foreach ($result->data as $fotos){ ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <span style="font-size: 12px; float:left; margin:5px 0 2px 10px;">  
    <a target="_blank" class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $fotos->link ?>">
    <img width="90" src="<?= $fotos->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
    <span style="font-weight:bold; float:left;"></span>
    <span style="float:right;"><span style="color:red; font-weight:bolder;">❤ </span><?= $fotos->likes->count ?></span>
    </span><?php } //Biter ?>
}
else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you use the `switch into and out of` PHP mode, which is a _good thing to do_, then it is worthwhile using [PHP: Alternative syntax for control structures - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). It is more readable. And gives clues to the programmer that you are 'mixing and matching' PHP mode with text output. Again, it is a good thing to be doing.

Comment: Yeah I would recommend using <?php echo $variable; ?> or <?= $variable; ?> if your server supports it within your massive echo statement. It will be a lot easier to manage and debug when needed. Happy to give an example if you like.

Comment: Also there is no need for the else part of the above statement as its doing nothing :)

Comment: @standej, i did what you suggested. It now works if the post doesnt have an instagramid field (so the "else" part works), but now it won't show the loop. (the part before the loop works) can you please help me out? many thanks in advance. The new code is here: http://codepaste.net/kiii5a

and that's the output: http://imagebin.ca/v/2RR48b6aYyWI